# Sharepoint errors

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint, moss

I have created a .net web part and deployed it on the sharepoint site. When I preview it, the sharepoint throws up an error saying "An error occured when previewing the Web Part"

The code in the web part is as follows

```
        Dim myweb As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context)
        'Dim mylist As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList = myweb.Lists(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("BedList").ToString())
        Dim mylist As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList = myweb.Lists("{80F6F320-E1F5-42EB-A2FB-895EAE00F589}")
        Dim items As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection = mylist.Items

        For Each item As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem In items
            returnString = returnString + "<br/>" + item("Status").ToString() + " For " + item("Title").ToString + "<br/>"
        Next
```

Does anyone know why this would not work. I can not get hold of the execption thrown. 
any help would be greatful

Comment: Have you checked the SharePoint logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should make your exceptions visible by changing the following in the web.config

CallStack = true

```
    <SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="false">
```

CustomErrors = Off

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Then you will see the real exception

You can also try obtain the current web using the following code:

```
Dim myweb As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web
```

Other problem could be related with wrong listId ou ListName when you try to obtain the list.

Hope it helps

Comment: When I  do that 
An error occured when previewing the Web Part.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPreview.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)

Comment: I can see the stack but no exception thrown

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking whether myList is nothing before doing myList.Items

Answer (score 0):

Also look for <compilation..> tag and set it to

<compilation debug="true"..>

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the "BedList" key to the correct web.config file?