# SharePoint 2007 Custom Page Error

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have created a custom aspx page and deploy into \12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS folder,

I trying to access the page via url e.g: http://sharepoint2007/sites/mySite/_layouts/DocLibrary.aspx,

then I hit "Unknown Error" in the page.

But it work fine when I "View in Browser" (local host) via Visual Studio.

The environment is in MOSS 2007, am I missing start some services? Please help...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily change the web.config file so you can see the true error.

See:

- [SharePoint - An unexpected error has occurred.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648910/sharepoint-an-unexpected-error-has-occurred)
- [Sharepoint errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590047/sharepoint-errors)
- [An unexpected error has occurred.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997803/an-unexpected-error-has-occurred)
- [Sharepoint “Unknown Error” debugging - but can't turn on CallStack… ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468921/sharepoint-unknown-error-debugging-but-cant-turn-on-callstack)

Comment: I have solved this anyway, by deploy the dll into the bin folder